# A formula to copy and past data between sheets as values only

Tags: google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet I have a query that gets data from different sheets (tabs) and pastes them into a Master sheet (tab):

```
=query({Sheet1!A:H; Sheet2!A2:H}, "Select * where Col1<>'' ")
```

Data in this Master sheet however, cannot be sorted, and I need to.

I found that if I manually copy and paste data into another sheet (tab) as "values only" I can then sort them.

So I need a query formula that does just this: automatically gets data from my Master sheet and copy and pastes them into a Master2 sheet as values only.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand why it "cannot be sorted". Why not use add something like "order by Col1 desc" to the query string? Then it's sorted.

Answer (score 2):

The result of QUERY or other similar functions can't be sorted by using the UI sort functions because the values are calculated every time that a recalculation is made in the spreadsheet but we could sort those values by using in formula sort features. In the case of QUERY we could use the [ORDER BY clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by) but also the [SORT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en).